# Гугл скрипт, чтобы удалять сообщения без файлов и оставлять остальные

Tags: google-apps-script

Я написал скрипт, который удаляет сообщения почты.

Как отредактировать этот скрипт, чтобы он оставлял сообщения с вложениями?

```
const SPAMMEREMAIL = 'SPAMERMAIL@mail.com';

async function trigger() {
  if (SPAMMEREMAIL.length < 3)
    throw new Error('Danger of deleting all content!');

  const threads = Gmail.Users.Threads.list('me', {
    q: `(from:${SPAMMEREMAIL})`,
  });

  if (threads && threads.threads) {
    threads.threads.forEach(thread => Gmail.Users.Threads.remove('me', thread.id));
  }

  const trashThreads = Gmail.Users.Threads.list('me', {
    q: `(from:${SPAMMEREMAIL}) is:trash`,
  });

  if (trashThreads && trashThreads.threads) {
    trashThreads.threads.forEach(thread => Gmail.Users.Threads.remove('me', thread.id));
  }
}
```

Comment: Зачем там `async`? Код от этого умнее не выглядит.

Comment: я не очень разбираюсь в этом языке(( может у вас есть предложение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое легкое, можно получить сообщения без вложений, не треды, а после удалить их. Треды нужны для другого.

```js
/**
 * Привязывается к триггеру по времени
 */
function triggerActionsDeleteMessagesWithoutAttacmentByQuery() {
  const QUERY = 'from:oshli.a.er@gmail.com';
  if (QUERY.length < 3)
    throw new Error('Danger of deleting all content!');
  const res = deleteMessagesWithoutAttacmentByQuery_(QUERY);
  res.forEach(s => console.log(s));
}

/**
 * Удаляет сообщения без вложений
 * 
 * @param {string} query
 * @returns {string[]}
 */
function deleteMessagesWithoutAttacmentByQuery_(query) {
  const messages = Gmail.Users.Messages.list('me', {
    q: `${query} -has:attachment`
  });

  if (!messages?.messages?.length) return [];

  const ids = messages.messages.map(message => message.id);

  Gmail.Users.Messages.batchDelete({
    ids
  }, 'me');

  return ids;
}
```

Немного добавлю:

1. Разбил на две функции, как принято в языке - точка входа и параметризированный функционал
2. Программа позволяет удалять сообщения из тредов. Например, пришло сообщение без вложения и в этот же тред, тут же, попало сообщение с вложением. Первое будет удалено.

Comment: Круто!!!! Спасибо!!!! Попробую!!!

Comment: Скажите, а почему этот скрипт не срабатывает по триггерам в 10 минут? руками если выполняю, все норм. Предыдущий почему-то срабатывал

Comment: @БулатМустафин, без полного проекта трудно сказать.

Comment: Я взял ваш скрипт и скопировал его , ничего больше. А потом поставил в настройках «запускать по триггеру» . Что-то еще надо было указать?

Comment: Создал отдельный вопрос для вашего удобства https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1564828/%d0%95%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b3%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%b8-%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%bb-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%be%d0%bd-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bb-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b3%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%83