# Есть триггер и гугл скрипт, как сделать чтобы он срабатывал по триггеру?

Tags: google-apps-script

Триггер- каждые 10 минут
Если выполняю скрипт руками, все работает хорошо, а по триггеру выдает ошибку
Как сделать чтобы по моему триггеру отрабатывал этот код?

```
/**
 * Привязывается к триггеру по времени
 */
function triggerActionsDeleteMessagesWithoutAttacmentByQuery() {
  const QUERY = 'from:spamer@gmail.com';
  if (QUERY.length < 3)
    throw new Error('Danger of deleting all content!');
  const res = deleteMessagesWithoutAttacmentByQuery_(QUERY);
  res.forEach(s => console.log(s));
}

/**
 * Удаляет сообщения без вложений
 * 
 * @param {string} query
 * @returns {string[]}
 */
function deleteMessagesWithoutAttacmentByQuery_(query) {
  const messages = Gmail.Users.Messages.list('me', {
    q: `${query} -has:attachment`
  });

  if (!messages?.messages?.length) return [];

  const ids = messages.messages.map(message => message.id);

  Gmail.Users.Messages.batchDelete({
    ids
  }, 'me');

  return ids;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что за ошибку выдает?

Comment: Что за ошибка? Процитируйте или добавьте скриншот

Comment: Приложил в вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы должны привязать соответствующую функцию к триггеру события. В данном случае это не `trigger`, а `triggerActionsDeleteMessagesWithoutAttacmentByQuery`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]